# XML comment with reference to file

Tags: c#, xml, comments

I want to add reference to file to xml comment for class. I can do it so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Condition with the content of the text <a href="file:///d:/a.jpg">file</a>
/// </summary>
```

How I can to use relative path to file?

Comment: I have no idea what your requirement is

Comment: relative to my project (maybe bin\Debug)

Comment: I can recommend considering how links are defined in **<a>** xml nodes (absolute and relative) here and then try to incorporate them in source code http://www.xmlnews.org/docs/xml-basics.html

Answer (score 1):

In Sandcastle paths are relative to the working folder (the `.\Working` folder under the output path set in the settings). To specify a path relative to your project, prefix it with `{@ProjectFolder}`. For example:

```xml
<a href="{@ProjectFolder}/a.jpg">File</a>
```

You can find a complete list of such replacement tags here:

> [Customizing the Build Process - Replacement Tags](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/69d998a7-1af5-4bf5-889b-59cd00b64000.htm)

---

Did you know you can replace `cref` with `href` in the documentation tags:

```xml
<see href="http://www.example.com/">Example</see>

<seealso href="http://www.example.com/">Example</seealso>
```